# How to remove reperitive code in if statements

Tags: system-verilog

Trying to make this piece of  existing code more compact.

```
if(argA) {
     struct_A_s addr;
     Chunk of common code;
   }
   else if(argB) {
      struct_B_s addr
      Chunk of common code;
  `enter code here` }
   else {
      struct_C_s  addr;
      Chunk of common code;
   }

I wish to do something similar to the lines below.
```

The way it is written below addr is not getting the correct structure.

```
   if(argA) {
      struct_A_s addr;
   }
   else if(argB) {
      struct_B_s addr
   }
   else {
       struct_C_s  addr;
   }

Chunk of common code;
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: difficult to say without understanding how `addr` is used in the `common code`. Most likely creating a function for the common code with `addr` as an argument will work. Then you will just use the function name in the conditional clauses.

Comment: The code you show in not SystemVerilog.

Comment: Thanks Serge -dave_59, Yes:), the braces are basically begin and end.

Comment: You really need to provide a little more detail, and how is it not giving you the correct structure.

Answer (score 0):

Your second set of code is executed in zero time, there is no time deltas, thus immediately after this code has been parsed, your resulting structure will likely still be unknown until a delta time later.  My guess is that in the "chunk of common code" there is some level of delay that is causing the addr value to be updated.